# How to organize Labels into folders in Google Bookmarks?

Tags: google-bookmarks

In Gmail we can organize our Labels into "folders", which is a really nice feature.

I use Google Bookmarks and due to having lots of bookmarks, I now also have a lot of Labels.

Is there any way to organise Labels into "folders" in Google Bookmarks?

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Google Bookmark extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jdnejaepfmacfdmhkplckpfdcjgbeode). It allows you do create nested labels and see them in a tree.

Comment: I would like a "cloud" solution though

Comment: You could try [this](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/78308). I haven't tried it but it apparently created nested labels within Google bookmarks

Comment: it sort of only modifies the interface. So basically what I see is that way, however if I have 15 Labels inside the "Technology" label and if I search for labels with "technology" those labels inside the technology label wouldn't show up

Comment: @Greg: But does this only work with Chrome? What if you later use another browser?

Comment: @w3d - The extension is Chrome specific so if you change browser it won't work anymore.